# Mixing C++ code with C code in a library produces undefined symbol errors

Tags: c++, linker, libraries

I have a library that consists of some .c modules and some .cpp modules.  I assume that's fine when the library is linked into a C++ main program.  But when I attempt to link that library into a C program, I get linker errors for 'standard C++ library' modules.

```
gcc -o PSEQ.app -Xlinker --allow-shlib-undefined pseq.app.o -L../librep -lrep

..librep/ssuinventbean.cpp:62: undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_string()'
```

The program in question is not written in C++ - and it does not reference the ssuinventbean.cpp module.  I asked a similar question about unreferenced shared library modules complaining about stuff called from there, and was told that the **--allow-shlib-undefined** linker flag could be used to get around that.  I tried using that flag in the gcc command above, but obviously it doesn't work as advertised when the library in question is a *statically linked* library.

Normally, that wouldn't be a problem.  I can make sure that all the modules in my application libraries have all of their references satisfied.  But in this case, the reference is to the standard C++ library, which I assume would've been included if the main module of the program in question were in C++.  So, catch-22?  Can I not have C++ code in a library if that library will be linked against a non-C++ app - even if the .cpp module in question is never referenced?  Do I have to segregate all C++ library code into its own .a files to be included only when building apps that call that code?

Comment: [Name mangling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling) maybe?

Comment: I just tried using g++ instead of gcc on the command line, and the stdcpp library reference errors went away.  I guess invoking g++ caused them to be pulled in automatically.  But still, this is not a C++ program, and it does not use any of the .cpp stuff in my librep.a module, so it's kind of weird to have to compile it in C++ mode just to satisfy C++ dependencies in an unused library module.  Any way to get around that?  I assume having the stdcpp stuff linked in won't hurt anything, but still...

Comment: Does compiling the library as c++ and exporting the functions you need as `extern "C"` work?

Comment: The C++ modules in the library are obviously compiled as c++.  There's no overriding 'compile the library' mode, so...  I don't think extern "C" would help anything - since the 'missing' stuff is standard C++ 'string' class.  Anyway, using g++ on the linking command line fixed the undefined 'string' references - it's just that I'm not using them, so it's weird to have to include them in my binary...

Comment: That's strange indeed. Which stdcpp functions/classes are you using? Maybe some of them use string internally, although I'm not sure about that.

Comment: I don't know which stdcpp classes I'm using (i.e., I didn't write the .cpp module - I'm just attempting to port the library and an app that uses it from AIX to linux).  What I do know is that I'm not using the *object* that uses *any* cpp classes - but because it's in a library I'm linking to, I have to link my app with g++ in order to resolve them.  And by resolve them, I guess that means that the linker as invoked by g++ links the standard C++ libraries into my app, which doesn't use them.  That's pretty nasty, IMO.

Comment: Actually, I think I may be mistaken about the reason for this.  I just tried implementing a trivial test case, and I got no undefined references for my unused C++ module.  Also, the fact that the gnu linker will report undefined references to library members if you don't present the libraries in the correct order implies that the linker doesn't pull in unreferenced library modules at all... no?

Answer (score 0):

I found out what was causing this.  It turned out that somebody had put a variable definition into a .h file that was pulled into this .cpp file.  I guess it's undefined what the compiler will do with a global variable in a .h file (it could end up getting defined in multiple .c or .cpp files that pull it in).

Anyway the .cpp file in question apparently pulled in that .h file as extern "C" code, which caused something else to pull in the .cpp module (presumably to pick up the global variable).  After I commented out the global variable in the .h file, the app was able to build with gcc instead of g++ on the linker line in my makefile.  Problem solved.

It turns out that the link maps generated in linux by these flags are *very* useful.  Told me that the global variable was what caused the otherwise unreferenced .cpp module to be included...

```
MAPFLAGS = -Xlinker --cref -Xlinker -Map=MAP
```